# Как в цикле проверить, есть ли в массиве 1 переменная а и b, если нет, то перейти к следующeму массиву?

Tags: php, циклы

Допустим есть 10 массивов, в которых по 5 значений, и есть переменные `a` и `b`.

Нужно проверить, есть ли переменная `a` и `b` в первом массиве. Eсли нет, то искать в другом массиве, а если ничего не найдет, то вывести -- совпадений не найдено.

Comment: А нет ли готовых функций, если циклы так напрягают? [Всмотреться](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.array.php)

Comment: @MBo искал вроде нет

Comment: Ну как же так... array_key_exists и array_search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php
$Search = 'ошибка 1';
function SearchErrors($search){
    $Errors1 = ['ошибка 1','ошибка 2','ошибка 3','ошибка 4','ошибка 5'];
    $Errors2 = ['ошибка 6','ошибка 7','ошибка 8','ошибка 9','ошибка 10'];
    $val = array_search($search, $Errors1);
    if ($val !== false){
        return 'Название ошибки - '.$Errors1[$val].' Ключ ошибки в массиве - '.$val;
    } else {
        $val1 = array_search($search, $Errors2);
        if($val1 !== false) {
            return 'Название ошибки - ' . $Errors2[$val1] . ' Ключ ошибки в массиве - ' . $val1;
        } else {
            return 'Ошибка не найдена';
        }
    }
}
print_r(SearchErrors($Search));
```